# Is this javascript code vulnerable to XSS

Tags: javascript, xss, poc

I have a simple `example.js` file that that is included in a html
`<script src="example.js"></script>`

```
'use strict';

function getURLParameter(name) {
  return new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(name)
}

function myFunction() {
    var myParam = '?my_param=' + getParam('my_param');
    $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: 'https://example.com' + clientParam,
    type: 'GET',
    [....]
}
```

Is the above javascript vulnerable to XSS ? I would have thought that `var myParam = '?my_param=' + getParam('my_param')` or even the part inside the avax call when doing the string concatenation would be but I can't break the string and the `"` gets replaced by `'\"'`

for example something as simple as this

`https://mypage.com?my_param=test';alert(1);`

I thought would replace `var myParam = '?my_param=' + getParam('my_param');` by
`var myParam = '?my_param=test';alert(1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

JavaScript does not execute strings returned from functions as if they were JS source code. They are *just* strings.